# Django authentication middleware denies login consistently

Tags: django, authentication

Preface: I taught myself how to use Django a couple of years ago, developed a webapp, handed the keys to my clients, and haven't had to do much with the app since then, nor have I developed with Django since then.

**The Problem**

A lot of users cannot log in successfully, and this appears to be a persistent problem for those it affects. However, I cannot for the life of me figure out what these users have in common. They use different operating systems, different browsers, access the site at different times of day/week/month. It's a reliable failure that doesn't seem to follow a pattern at all.

**Specifics**

The webapp is running on Windows, Django 1.0, and uses MySQL as the database. Sessions are stored to the database.

**Eliminating Possible Causes**

It's not a "wrong username/password" problem, unfortunately. That would be easy. No, the thousands of users of this webapp use the same username and password. (Not my preference or choice!) Furthermore, the failure-to-authenticate is not accompanied by a username/password error message.

Now, the site *does* work for most of the users. So I know that the basic authentication configuration is correct: the `MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and `INSTALLED_APPS` tuples contain the correct contrib lines. `LOGIN_URL`, `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, and `LOGOUT_URL` are all set correctly. The URL dispatcher works, the views work, etc.

The fact that it is a consistent, ongoing failure for the affected users means that it's not a load problem.

For some affected users, using a different browser will fix the problem. For others it does not. And it's not necessarily a question of peculiar browser configuration, because a lot of the users who tried second browsers did so by downloading/installing a second browser for the first time, presumably using the default configuration. (Note that the users are largely not "power users".)

**Reproducing the Error**

The hardest part of all of this is that I have never had a failed login on any of my computers or browsers, so it's impossibly difficult to tackle the debugging process.

The problem is reproducible, though. The primary client's computer, when she is logged in to it and using IE 7 or 8, fails to log in, with the expected behaviour. The hitch: it is *not* reproducible when *I* am logged in to the same computer, regardless of the browser I use.

**Why I'm Asking Here**

I do most of my development in PHP/MySQL. When I'm looking for login problems I look for problems in the username/password, cookies, server-side sessions, browsers, etc. I write debugging code to dump the server/cookie variables to the screen, etc.

Unfortunately I don't know how to debug Django middleware. I don't even know what type of problem this could possibly be.

**Finally**

I have been wracking my brain for days. Several months ago I went through the same thing, also for days, before it was deemed a lower priority than some other projects I had. But now it's back.

I cannot for the life of me see a pattern. I'm hoping some of you have some suggestions!

**EDITED**

Here's some of the relevant code, by request.

*in settings.py*

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
)

LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
LOGOUT_URL = '/logout/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

*in urls.py*

```
(r'^login/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name': 'login.html'}),  
(r'^logout/', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'template_name': 'logout.html'}),
```

*in login.html*

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Please Log In</h1>
{% if form.errors %}<p>Your username and password didn't match. Please try again.</p>{% endif %}
<form method="post" action="/login/">
<p>{{ form.username.label_tag }} {{ form.username }}</p>
<p>{{ form.password.label_tag }} {{ form.password }}</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="login" /></p>
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You talk about everything but you miss the most interesting part:

how the users make login? i mean, the form is your's or django? the view is your code or django? can you paste some snippets of this code? are you talking about the admin interface?

Once i have a similar problem with a javascript error: the password was send to the server twice, i mean: passwordpassword

Do you use firebug or something to view the data of request?

Comment: The view is Django's, and it's not the Admin interface. The form is mine, and very simple. No javascript in use. I've added some of the pertinent code, though.

Comment: May usernames and/or passwords contain non-ASCII characters? If so, is the content-encoding clearly specified in the HTML head of the login form and the same encoding used on the server side to decode form values? (Browsers normally encode form data in the character set specified in the HTML page.)

Comment: Alas, no, the only username and password pair in use is plain ASCII, and "problem" users include people whose computers have never been internationalized. That said, the HTML header specifies the charset as iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

it's very unlikely that the error is in the stock django middleware, so you don't need to debug that, but you can add a bunch of logging statements in your code and later analyze the logs. Python `logging` module works well for the purpose.

Comment: I did something similar to this. Because I can't think of anything in my own code that could even potentially contribute to the problem, given that all I'm doing is using the @login_required decorator, I wrote a quick-and-dirty custom app that basically replicates the login view of the auth middleware in my own code, so I can riddle it with as much debug logging as I want. I've had that running for about 5 days now, though, and haven't got anything that looks like it could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I'm not a Django/Python expert by any means. Just have some general advice to give.

Is the SQL server being pegged? Perhaps it's being overloaded, dropping some of the login requests through a timeout of some sort.

Is everything running off of one server, or multiple servers? If multiple, there could be timeouts between them, or some sort of syncing issues.

Comment: Everything's running off one server, but I've ruled out load issues because for the people who can't log in, they've never been able to log in, regardless of when they try. And it's not generally a heavily-loaded server... it spikes after a newsletter goes out once a month, but other than that usage is light but ongoing.